# fb:visible-to-connection not working in IE7 standards

Tags: facebook

I have the following code in a Facebook application:

```
    <table width="520" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background:url(comp-scd-like.jpg) no-repeat;height:380px;width:260px;">
<fb:visible-to-connection><a href="competitions/facebook.htm"><img src="comp-scd-lg.jpg"  border="0" style="display:block;" /></a></fb:visible-to-connection></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In IE8, Firefox, Chrome etc it works fine, however in IE7 Standards, using the developer mode, it doesn't show any content whatsoever.

Any ideas why this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a caution than a fix.

Ensure you are not an administrator of your page as being one fires both visible-to-connection and the else.

Very annoying!